# Does Worksheet_Change event work on Office 2016 for Mac?

Tags: excel, vba

## What I want to know

I'm new to Excel VBA. I currently study it with a Mac and **Office 2016 for Mac** until I get a Windows PC. I coded as the textbook says, but it didn't work. Nothing happened, even an error. I want to know the cause. **Is there any mistake in my code? Or do not events support Mac?**

## What my code is supposed to do

I tried to use `Worksheet_Change` event.

1. Input or change a value in any cell.
2. Output the target cell address to the immediate window.

**Here is my code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Debug.Print "Target cell: " & Target.Address
End Sub
```

**Here is a screenshot of my Excel and VBE windows:**
[image: Screenshot of Excel and VBA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be in the Sheet1 module, not the ThisWorkbook module.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It works properly now! Thank you! Are Worksheet_*** events available only in sheet modules?

Comment: For individual worksheets you use the Worksheet_*** events and they go in the worksheet modules. However there are also workbook level events like Workbook_SheetChange which go in the ThisWorkbook module and are triggered by events on any sheet in the workbook.